# New spawn rules for Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A while back when I was researching spawning rules, I found that if a monster in the 32m - 128m area (which randomly despawns over time), would actually not despawn if it was moving. So if the Mob was in a water channel and moving, then it wouldn't despawn if the player moved so that the mob was over 32m, as long as the mob didn't reach 128m+.

Is this still true in the newest 1.8 version?

Answer (score 2):

All of the spawn rules can be found [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawning#Mob_spawning). In case the website is down, here's a useful excerpt:

> Monsters (not holding items or wearing armor) and squid (but not animals), including hostile wolves as of 1.1, can cease to exist, or "despawn", under certain conditions:
>
> A mob that has had no player within 32 blocks of it for more than 30 seconds has a 1 in 800 chance of despawning on each game tick (1/20th of a second). Therefore, the half-life of monsters not within 32 blocks of a player is 27.73 seconds (after the initial 30 seconds have elapsed).
>
> A mob will immediately despawn if there is no player within 128 blocks of it. Note that this is a Euclidean sphere, not a cylinder from map top to bottom and not a taxicab sphere (which is more like an octahedron). Example: A mob at 0/y/0 will remain at least 30 seconds (as above) if the player moves to 65/y/65 (real distance 91.9), but despawns immediately if the player moves to 91/y/91 (real distance 128.7).
>
> All hostile mobs (including those that are holding items) in a world will despawn if the difficulty is set to peaceful, regardless as to where the player is positioned in the world.
>
> In multiplayer, despawning does not occur while there are no players in the game.
>
> A monster which has been named with a name tag will not despawn. However, one created from a renamed spawn egg will despawn as normal.
>
> If a monster is holding any items or wearing any armor that was given by a player or picked up from the ground, it will not despawn.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have answered the OP's question - he specifically asked about whether mobs despawn when more than 32 and less than 128 blocks away, if they are moving.

Comment: "These are all the rules"... and the OP's hypothetical rule is not part of them. I think that makes it an answer. (The OP probably didn't realise that there's an average 1 minute delay between moving 32m away and mobs despawning, and erroneously attributed the effect to the movement.)