# What are the relative ratios for spawns of hostile mobs in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I remember there being something like a 2:2:1:1 ratio way back when but I don't know about the rates for endermen or witches.
PC version 1.8.8

Comment: Just googled it, I can't seem to find any numbers about this.

Comment: Check out this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184384/new-spawn-rules-for-minecraft-1-8

Comment: I tried googling it myself, with similar results.

Comment: And that set of rules does not include the ratios, APCoding.  Maybe I'll have to do some nonsense with MCEdit or something.

Answer (score 1):

Hostile Mobs is a tag for all Hostile Mobs.
Every mob should or has his own spawn rate, because every mob is different and OP, bigger or if you kill it you can profit of it really fast.

There are different ways a mob can spawn. It could be that the mob spawns in group, different mobs also spawns in **different light levels**. If Zombies wouldn't have anything they know they can spawn they won't spawn. But they spawn in holes because of the light level. That's why you should place torches to change the **light level**.

Normaly the mob should spawn already when all their spawn conditions are at the area.

Everything is written here, for every mob you want.

The best site is this one:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawning#Mob_spawning

Just search the mob you want, as example:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ghast#Spawning

Peolpe want to know more details to farm mobs
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Mob_farm

Comment: Please include summaries of the linked information to prevent link rot. Otherwise, this looks good :)